# Serialization in GWT 2.5.1

Tags: gwt, serialization, gwt-2.5

I've updated my project from GWT 2.4.0 to GWT 2.5.1 and suddenly a specific RPC serialization has stopped work (all other are still working).

I have this class:

```
public class StatusChangeMapEntity extends RecordStamp implements Serializable {

    private HashMap<WFStatus, Pair<WFPhase, ArrayList<Pair<AppUser, Date>>>> map;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The exception message is:

```
Attempt to deserialize an object of type class Pair when an object of type class Slide is expected
```

The class Slide extends StatusChangeMapEntity and is the object that is being deserialized.

Any ideias how to solve this problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem. Basically I've created a class extending the HashMap:

```
public class MapStatusChanges extends HashMap<WFStatus, Pair<WFPhase, ArrayList<Pair<AppUser, Date>>>> {
   ...
}
```

And then created a CustomSerializer to the MapStatusChanges.

It's not a generic solution, but it works until this problem is solved at GWT.

Hope this helps....