# GWT 2.5 Can't serialize HashMaps in request

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-2.5

I upgraded to 2.5 and I can't no longer pass a HashMap.
I don't get an error, but deserialization of the request gets stuck.
That was working in all previous releases, even before 2.0

The problem appears when the request parameters are deserialized.
Serialization of Responses works without  any problems.

`Parameters` class extends `HashMap`

```
        HashMap value = new HashMap();
        value.put("CODE", "VALUE");

        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
        values.add(value);


        Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
        parameters.setValues(values);

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(parameters);

        greetingService.greetServer("MyService","MyMethod", list, new AsyncCallback<String>()
```

Comment: Did you try `Map value = new HashMap();` instead? or add `HashMap<String,String>`

Comment: None of it solves the problem. Anyway <String, String> is not option for me. Reproducing this is very easy: Just create a sample GWT project and change the GreetingService, pass a HashMap, and use GWT 2.5

Comment: Seems related with this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620299/serialization-in-gwt-2-5-1

Comment: Also there is an issue in gwt about this problem: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7628

Comment: @Manolo thank you for your answer. I've seen this post, I couldn't possibly do what was suggested there. It was actually issue 7779, See Thomas' response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be hitting [issue 7779](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7779). Try GWT 2.5.1.

Comment: Yes that was it. GWT 2.5.1 fixed this. Thanks.